# How can I compensate for vim and make not using the same working directory?

Tags: make

I have a project where `make` and `vim` are run from different directories. The project structure looks like this:

```
root/
  ├── build
  │   └── gmake_linux
  │       ├── bin
  │       │   └── Debug
  │       └── obj
  │           └── Debug
  :
  ├── include
  :
  ├── source
  :
  ├── test
  :
```

I use the project root as my working directory for everything, including a custom Makefile. However, the "real" build work is done two levels down in the `build/gmake_linux` directory. The heavy-lifting is done by Makefiles generated by `premake5`.

Because of this, messages containing filenames tend to contain a bunch of extra `../..`, like so:

```
==== Building run_tests (debug) ====
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aghast/Code/aghast /libaghast/build/gmake_linux'
[1646719388.628151980] Running tests...
../../source/bytes.c:72: Unittest failed in unittest_ba_compare_lt
  ba_compare(ba1, ba2) < 0
```

So when I invoke something like `:make` or `:make test`, I get bad handling of the resulting files.

Is there some clever way to fix up the source paths so that Vim can process them correctly?

Comment: Not relevant at all, but are you guys making those diagrams from scratch or is there a handy shortcut I'm missing?

Comment: On linux, `man tree`. I replaced the content lines with colon (':') characters myself.

Comment: You could have a look at the `%D` and `%X` specifiers for `errorformat` (`:help E379`). Or get your compiler to print absolute paths. Otherwise you could use an autocommand on `QuickFixCmdPost` and manipulate `getqflist()` and `setqflist()`.